# Nggettext globalization + grunt automization + jade templates

Tags: gruntjs, pug, globalization, language-translation, grunt-angular-gettext

I found [this super informative and useful article](https://lostechies.com/gabrielschenker/2014/02/11/angularjspart-12-multi-language-support/) about globalization using angular's gettext directive and grunt. Problem is, it seems to extract from `.html` files only and I can't really get it running with jade.

I am using `Node.js` for my server, together with `Express.js`, so I convert my `.jade` files to `.html` files on the fly, on each user request. I really like the way express and jade fit together, so I am searching for a solution, which extracts translations from those jade files.

For now I tried changing the grunt task snippet to:

```
grunt.initConfig({

        nggettext_extract: {
            pot: {
                files: {
                    'po/template.pot': ['**/*.jade']
                }
            }
        }
});
```

And also adding the translation directive as I do for all other angular directives, e.g.:

```
h3(translate) About
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add jade file support to angular-gettext you would need to modify [extract.js](https://github.com/rubenv/angular-gettext-tools/blob/master/lib/extract.js) in the [angular-gettext-tools](https://github.com/rubenv/angular-gettext-tools) project because that is what is actually scanning and extracting the text. It doesn't look like a trivial change.

I would suggest a different approach. See if you can generate html for all the jade files as part of a build process and then run the angular-gettext tools against that. Then you continue to develop as you like but you do not to need to add jade support to angular-gettext.